# R: write a high-quality GUI for an R-project

Tags: r, user-interface

I have written a piece of R-code that performs a numerical computation. Now, I want to implement it into a nice GUI. I know that there are some R-packages, that allow to create GUIs from within R (e.g. gWidgets, RGtk2, ...). However, they seem to be rather limited in the capabilities and complicate to build. So I thought about going the other way round and writing a windowed-program that incorporates my R-code.

Is it possible to write a nice GUI (for example in Visual Basic.NET or Java) that allows to gather some user inputs, call the R-computations and display the results?
I ask for Visual Basic because there is this new R-Open that comes along with Visual Studio which makes me think the two must offer natural ways of collaboration with each other. I also hope that I would be able to compile an exe with it in the end.

Thank you very much for you Help!
Bernd

Comment: Could it be that Shiny that you are looking for?

Comment: shiny is probably your best bet here

Comment: The problem with Shiny is, that it can only produce Web-Applications. So that one has to set up a server on which R is running and the users can make computations on the server by entering a specific URL in their browser. There is no way to create a normal application with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed R in C++ code. There are examples in the R source code and documentation.

Very briefly, you'll need to build a *shared DLL* version of R (i.e with the `--enable-R-shlib` option) from the source code, using the [Windows Tools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/). This is how GUIs like RStudio function.

The [R Admin manuals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Building-from-source) have detailed instructions. The [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) package might make this a bit easier.

With the shared DLL you could probably embed R in other languages (it works for [R in Python](https://rpy2.bitbucket.io/)).

Comment: This might be exactly what I was looking for. Strange that I never found this possibility be googling the web. Thank you!
I will read through the topic now ...